# Hide and show a table row onclick with jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, show

Disclamer:

Almost new to jQuery.

I'm trying to build something very easy with jquery, but my problem is that I'm working with tables, and my framework sometimes tends to add markup or classes to my table (I'm in the control panel of expressionengine), which is annoying. So essentially I don't have the freedom to control my structure as I wish.

Anyway, I'd like to create two  and hide and show them on click with jquery:

```
<th class="plus">+</th>
<th class="minus">-</th>
```

As I explained before, I can't put them in a div, so in order to hide and show them, I was thinking about something like that:

```
$('.plus', '.minus').click(function() {
  $(this).toggle();
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Which doesn't do anything really. Technically it works, especially if you use only one of them, and of course, I can use a toggle class like:

```
hidden {
display: none
}
```

and add to them with a toogleClass() but I was trying to do something cleaner without repeating myself.

Any thought?

Comment: using the class is much cleaner than toggle and show/hide

Comment: In css, or I should add an extra class in the html?

Comment: you need to use toggleClass

Comment: but one is hidden and the hide is shown, I mean one is display : none

Answer (score 0):

- Add a class (show-hide) to both the plus and minus icon
- Hide the minus icon using css
- in jquery, onclick show all the icons, and then hide the currently clicked icon

**HTML**

```
<div class="plus show-hide">
+
</div>
<div class="minus show-hide">
-
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.minus {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.show-hide').click(function() {
  $(".show-hide").show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1w3y1j9a/)**

Comment: But on click it has to alternate the status between plus and minus

Comment: @Matto: can u explain what u mean by alternate the status?. can you try the code snippet above, when u click on minus, if content is visible , it will hide, if not nothing happens, the same for plus, when u click on plus if the content is hidden it shows, if its already open nothing happens,

Comment: It's not the content that I want to hide and show, it's just the sign :)

Comment: <div class="minus"> is displayed none, the other not, alternate status means change them to the opposite

Comment: something like:
$('.plus').click(function() {
  $(this).next().show();
  $(this).hide();
 
});